# The network path was not found (0x80070035)

Tags: networking, windows-10, shared-folders

There are many questions for that issue already.

Still, I can't find any solution, and I use to face that issue anyway, at least once a month. So, I was looking to find or establish the right checklist to identify what is failing here.
Sometimes, one of the PCs can find the other one, sometimes both are blind.

- Both PCs have shared folders, in the same domain.
- Both PCs are connected to the same local network.
- Both PCs have their IP address generated by the router, and are present on the router interface.
- Ip Address of the target is not found - Ping does not answer on the IP
- Deactivating both firewalls does not help
- **Resets made the invisible PC pingable** (but not reachable by its name):

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

- Tried to reset Netbios:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nbtstat –R
```

Comment: This sounds like DNS. Are you trying to PING by hostname or IP?

Comment: Also, what is providing DHCP and DNS in your domain? Typically this is done by Active Directory servers, but you mentioned the addresses being "generated" (I assume you mean DHCP lease offered) by a router..?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question as the situation was not completely exact.
So, finally, after resets, PING answers with IP, not with hostname...
Also, yes, a router is providing the DHCP..

Comment: I see, that means DNS is failing in your network (the A record is missing). What is providing DNS - do you have a DNS server or is it the router?

Comment: Well, I was not so sure. And after having dug a little, it seems that I don't have any. Therefore, I found out that Netbios, within Windows, was in charge of naming the IPs.

Comment: I just  tried to reset  Netbios...

Comment: Indeed, I just found that the router interface was showing up the name sources of the PC : four names from DHCP, mDNS, netBios and UPnP

Comment: I finally got it by restarting the router.
I suppose that it fixed the local DNS...

Comment: NetBIOS is deprecated, by several years actually. Just FYI